# Is it possible to merge a list of spacy tokens into a doc

Tags: python, nlp, token, spacy

I have a document which I've tokenized using Spacy tokenizer.
I want to apply `ner` on a sequence of tokens(a section of this document).

Currently I'm creating a doc first and then applying `ner`

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
# tokens_list is a list of Spacy tokens
words = [tok.text for tok in tokens_list]

spaces = [True if tok.whitespace_ else False for tok in tokens_list]

doc = spacy.tokens.doc.Doc(blackstone_nlp.vocab,
      words=words, spaces=spaces)
doc = nlp.get_pipe("ner")(doc)
```

But this is not ideal because I loose their original ids within the document, which is important.

Is there a way to merge tokens into a doc and still maintain their ids(including other future [extensions](https://spacy.io/api/token#set_extension))?

Comment: Why do you want to merge them into a doc instead of re-using the original doc?

Comment: @polm23, Basically I have sectioned my large document into sections and I want to apply certain NLP operations(`ner`) on specific sections only, such as the conclusion or any paragraph within the document.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I guess you want to do that for speed reasons? I don't think there's a way to run a pipeline component only a given Span... Though you might want to open an issue about that. A simple workaround is to create a new doc like you do here and save the original starting id somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be using a corpus to manage your documents. Try [textacy](https://textacy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#working-with-many-texts) for managing documents and subsections.

Answer (score 0):

To merge a list of tokens back into `Doc` you may wish to try:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
txt = "This is some text"
doc = nlp(txt)
words = [tok.text for tok in doc]

spaces = [True if tok.whitespace_ else False for tok in doc]
doc2 = spacy.tokens.doc.Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)
```

Comment: I already have that implemented, but the problem is that I can't carry Spacy tokens ids and other extensions to the newly created `Doc`.

Comment: @Terms_of_Service. What you showed `spaces=[False]*len(token_str_list)` isn't exactly right.

Comment: @scign `Doc` class expects `spaces` to be list of `bool`s. You may try your luck with bare `tok.whitespace_`, but I think explicit is always better than implicit.